# How to see what is the cause of a 400 http bad request returned from WCF rest service while debugging

Tags: wcf, exception, configuration

Many posts here on SO asks for help in solving a 400 http bad request. However, I couldn't find a post that explains how to get the underlying cause of the exception.

Assume that both supplier and client running .NET, and also assume that we're on debug time:

1. If I'm the web service supplier, how can I make sure the client will recieve the reason for the bad request?
   (I tried decorating the web service class with the attribute `[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]`, but it seems to have no effect).
2. If I'm the web service client, how can I see what's the reason for the bad request?

Comment: Depends on what you are looking for, is this a wcf rest service?

Comment: The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
   will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
   a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
   message framing, or deceptive request routing). I am not sure you can pass the reason back to the client.

Comment: @mahlatse, yes, it's REST

Comment: If the request is not processed properly by the server, the error will not go into the WCF framework, so the built-in interface of WCF, IErrorhandler, will not handle it. I think the cause of the error should be recorded in the web server

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the exception in the fault in the rest service

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal("Could not complete process", ex);
                throw new WebFaultException<string>(
                       string.Format(ex.Message),
                            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
```

The above code will handle both scenarios, assuming you have a logger enabled, you can just get the log files on the server, the client would receive the exception message

I guess you could just send the client a friendly message so that they don't anything about your specific implementation, or just create a class that you can call

> [WebFaultException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.webfaultexception-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)< T >

with.

**EDIT 2**

If you are getting an issue before you can get the request, you can try the following

Add a FaultHandler to your Service

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class GenericErrorHandlingBehavior : Attribute, IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            // Adds a CoreServiceBehavior to each ChannelDispatcher
            foreach (var channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                var channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new GenericErrorHandlingBehavior());
            }
        }

        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            if (error is FaultException)
                return;//nothing to do if the error is a fault

            //the type cannot be determined[ default to this value]
            var exception = new FaultException<GenericServiceFault>(
                new GenericServiceFault(), new FaultReason(error.Message));

            MessageFault messageFault = exception.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, exception.Action);

        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The `GenericServiceFault` class is just a simple DataContract class,
You can then Log the error in your `ProvideFaultMethod`, or The `HandleError` method and provide a meaningful error to the user

You can use the `GenericErrorHandlingBehavior` on your service implementation as an attribute, i.e [GenericErrorHandlingBehavior]

Comment: The web service method is not executed in case of a bad request, so it wouldn't work

Comment: Updated the answer, you can can check if that would be a better approach